# laravel jsValidation error while using unique rule

Tags: php, validation, laravel, jsvalidation

I am having issue while using laravel unique rule in CreateRequest with [JsValidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation). Here is the Request code.

```
class CreateProductRequest extends Request
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            'factory_id' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required',
            'product_code' => 'required|unique:product',
            'un_code' => 'required|unique:product',
            'hs_code' => 'required|unique:product',
            'section' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'product_type' => 'required',
            'classification' => 'required',
            'main_product_market' => 'required',
            'custodian_user_id' => 'required'

        ];
    }
}
```

When I remove the unique field its fine. But with unique rules I would get 500 server error as follows
[image]

In console it reports

[image]

It worth noting that if I don't use the JSValidation Laravel will produce no errors

Update :

In the Debug Bar I am getting this error

`'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'name'' in /.../demo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:408:`

Comment: Your server is responding with a 500 error, which means you need to go look in your apache/nginx error logs for the answer.

Comment: @jszobody but this wont be if i just remove the unique from the rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was later solved. My issue was that I was not typeHinting the `CreateProductRequest` and was instead using `Request`.

I should have been typeHinted the extended Request class that declares the rules.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the same unique field for each item:

```
'product_code' => 'required|unique:product',
'un_code' => 'required|unique:product',
'hs_code' => 'required|unique:product',
```

I'm guessing `product` is your table, not the field.

I think this is what you may be after:

```
'product_code' => 'required|unique:product,product_code',
'un_code' => 'required|unique:product,un_code',
'hs_code' => 'required|unique:product,hs_code',
```

This would require each one of those fields to be unique.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

Comment: still having the same isssue

Comment: something intresting... If I dont use the JS Validation it will work fine.

Comment: I changed the answer to do unique:table,field - assuming product is the table, give that a go (checked js validations docs and they list it this way. `email' => 'unique:users,email_address`

Comment: Still same, I did use it before...no luck still i would get the same error

Comment: Do a `tail -f /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` - hit enter a few times to clear some space then trigger the validation again, it should be easier to see the error this way.